# mysql table data_length is more than 10 times larger then expected

Tags: mysql, innodb

This is an **InnoDB** table with **140,000** rows. The index size is negligible, and if I check all the column contents, the estimated total data should be around **10MB** to **20MB**. But it's more than **1.1GB**. Looking for suggestions for how I can track down the dark matter in the table that's inflating it so much? Thank you for any possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  2x-3x is typical; 10x is abnormal.  Did you recently do a big `DELETE`?

Comment: What was the value of `innodb_file_per_table` set _when_ the table was created?

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, I cleared out about a third of the rows (older data), and ran OPTIMIZE, but this didn't make a big difference to the data length. I don't think there will be a problem with the table structure - it's a table from CiviCRM, and widely used. I don't know about the innodb_file_per_table value. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

See [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html). When data is updated/removed, there will be gaps in the table space that are no longer in use.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was my first thought, but OPTIMIZE simply increased the table size slightly.

Comment: Show us the metric that says that the size "increased slightly".  This may give a clue on how to approach the puzzle.  (Even if you don't have the old info, the new info could give us a clue.)

Comment: I was just going by phpmyadmin, which showed 1.0GB before optimizing and 1.1GB after. In fact the data length is now 1.147GB